# MDX Allow member set only siblings in Roles-Dimension Data

Tags: ssas, parent-child, mdx, hierarchy, olap

Is it possbile to restrict a Role in Dimension Data by allowing him to see only siblings in the parent-child Hierarchy?
Example Hierarchy:

```
EMEA              100

  UK               50
     London        30
     Southampton   20

  France           50
      Paris        10
      Lyon         40
```

To see only:

```
  EMEA             100
     UK             50
     France         50
```

[image: Role]

Comment: You mean restrict access to "Cities"?

Comment: @SouravA  that's right...based on Roles, allowing to see the siblings (or deny the children)

Comment: @SouravA I've received the expected result with the following MDX statement ` NONEMPTY(descendants([Dim Branch Hierarchies].[Branch Hierarchy],,leaves),   
([Measures].[GrantedHi],StrtoMember(
 "([Dim Users].[Account Name].[Account Name].["+ Username()+ "])" 
 
 ))
)`

Comment: Great job. Good approach. Answer the question yourself. That way you would be helping someone who might have similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received the expected result with the following MDX statement

```
 NONEMPTY(
    descendants(
       [Dim Branch Hierarchies].[Branch Hierarchy]
       ,,leaves
    )
  , (
     [Measures].[GrantedHi]
    ,StrtoMember( 
        "([Dim Users].[Account Name].[Account Name].["+ Username()+ "])" 
     )
    ) 
)
```