# SSAS Pivot Table - Retrieve from parent-child hierarchy only the leaf and the first parent , not all the levels

Tags: sql, excel, ssas, parent-child, mdx

I have the following situation. User1 is authorized to see

```
UK (London and Northampton) .
```

`DimBrach` is a `parent-child hierarchy`. When `User1` wants to access the report I want him to see only the `leafs (London and Northampton)` and the first parent and not the entire hierarchy. 
How can I reach this in a `Pivot Table` or in `SSAS (MDX)` ?

[image]

Comment: Is there any dimension which holds the information that User1 is authorized to see data for London and Northampton?

Comment: @SouravA ..yes, there are 3 tables... DimBranch implemented with parent-child  , DimUsers and a Bridge table with the keys from those two tables

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply like this, in the SSAS project in Visual Studio:

1. Create a Role for the user
2. In the Role designer's Dimension Data tab, deselect/select dimension members as needed

You can check this is working by processing the cube, browsing it through VS and using the "Change User" button.  (No need to enter the user's password).

**ADDITION:**
To make role security less hard-coded you can use MDX statements in the Advanced tab of the Role Dimension Data tab, and populate a fact table controlling access.  You're already doing this, judging by your past [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005052/mdx-allow-member-set-only-siblings-in-roles-dimension-data/32008206#32008206).

As far as I know Excel pivot-tables are far less flexible than raw MDX in showing particular levels of a hierarchy.  The end user can view their pivot-table, right-click on a field and select the Show/Hide fields option, so they can control what they see.  But as far as I know there's no way for the developer to prevent them from seeing a particular level at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not the solution because in `Dimension Data` tab, using  `select/deselect ` members you also receive the entire path... For example , if I select only UK I will also get the path above to EMEA. Anyway, selecting and deselecting hierarchy members it's not a good idea.. I do not want to change the roles every time a User moves to other branch or new User is arrived... Imagine there are >50 roles